# Data types int and double in calculating e

Tags: c++

Why, when I use `double i` the output is (an approximation to) the value of *e*?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    double s=0;
    double i=1;
    for (int m=1;m<5;m++)
    {
        i=m*i;
        s=s+1/i;
    }
    cout<<s+1;
    return 0;
}
```

But when I use `int i`, the output is 2:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    double s=0;
    int i=1;
    for (int m=1;m<5;m++)
    {
        i=m*i;
        s=s+1/i;
    }
    cout<<s+1;
    return 0;
}
```

The variable that stores the value of *e* is `s`, which is `double`, so I was expecting that the datatype of `i` doesn't matter.

Comment: In your second snippet, the `1/i` part of the assignment statement is evaluated as **integer division**, so when `i` is anything greater than 1 it will yield zero.

Comment: `1/i` is still integer division.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The reason that the output is different when you use `double` or `int` for the `i` variable is because of the way that division works in C++. When you use integer division, the result of the division is also an integer. So, in the second example where `i` is an `int`, each time you perform the division `1/i`, the result is always an integer, which is then converted to a `double` and added to `s`. This means that some of the fractional parts of the calculation are being lost.

In the first example, where `i` is a `double`, the result of the division `1/i` is also a `double`, and the fractional parts of the calculation are preserved. This is why the output is different in the two cases.

One way to fix this would be to use the `1.0` instead of `1` in the division, like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    double s=0;
    int i=1;
    for (int m=1;m<5;m++)
    {
        i=m*i;
        s=s+1.0/i;
    }
    cout<<s+1;
    return 0;
}
```

This way, the `1.0` will be treated as a `double`, and the result of the division will also be a `double`, so the fractional parts of the calculation will be preserved.

Answer (score -2):

You're doing integer division on this line when `i` is an integer:

```
s=s+1/i;
```

You want to instead do floating point division:

```
s = s + 1.0 / i;
```